# how to get the most accurate location using GPS and AGPS with given time in android?

Tags: android, google-maps, gps

**I have a below requirement.**

**Find location of user from GPS and AGPS. (we are going to use Samsung Galaxy ACE mobile phone)**

**Note:** For every transaction first location will be the reference location for the next activities.

**Below are the constraint which has to be considered while solving this problem.**

1. user should be within 10meter range of the reference location. meaning (Reference location - current location) <= 10meter (distance calculation by **Locaiton** class API).
2. Location has to found in the given period of time.
   let say 20-25sec for finding each locaiton. the time can be extended to max 35sec.
3. My user is always be outside of the Shop while taking the reference location and then inside for all the other activities.

**What I am doing**

1. find the reference location with accuracy of 30m with 25sec of time. store this in static variable.
2. find the location for next actiivty and calculate the difference. if difference >=10m tell user to perform that activity again.

**My Queries**

1. Is this possible with such fine accuracy in the distance with given Time and place?
2. How google calculate this distance?
3. Does google finds the location with such accuracy? or what is the accuracy of Google Map using GPS? for e.g. at given particular time and location given by the Google MAP by GPS how much it is accurate? like if i am standing near to my BANK then what is difference between co-ordinates on the google map on the server and the co-ordinate given by google map through GPS on mobile phone.

I have did enough experiment on this problem and finally came here for help.
i did the observation by doing variation in timing, place, accuracy. still need to find one final solution. as we have to answer the client whether it is possible or not?

Answer (score 0):

1. The GPS can provide most accurate match but only outdoors. It is possible to achieve such accuracy but not guaranteed.
2. There are formulates for finding distance between two points on a sphere. However, for rough approximations euclidean distance can be tried.
3. The location and its accuracy depends on client side GPS. Google just reads it.