# How to accuratly find other Android users within a radius of 200ft ( How did Color do it?)

Tags: android, gps, geolocation, proximity

I'm working on a app which requires that a device with this app installed will automatically find other users within a maximum radius of 200ft (worst case scenario 300ft, but that's pushing it) and/or a minimum radius of 40ft.

Ive tried the obvious solution of using GPS and a MYSQL query that query's our location table for other users within the 200ft radius, but as you probably would guess this is not incredibly accurate and if the device uploads coordinates that are off by over 200ft the server will return a list of users that are not within proximity. While I would prefer to just get the app to work the way it was meant to I'd rather the server return no users than false positives.

I know there's probably no simple way to do it accurately, but what other options do I have? And how did Color manage to do it? With all the tech in the avg smartphone and all the location based apps this has to be possible to do.

Answer (score 1):

200ft (60m) is no Problem for GPS. Usually GPS is below 10m.
You even have a location.getAccuracy() method which you should evaluate
Just use GPS as your only location source. do not use cell tower location provider, when you want accuracy < 60m.
Of course inside a building, when you are sitting at your desktop GPS will not work, or is off by 60m.
GPS needs a view to open sky not obstructed (by dense materials).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this question:

[how to get the most accurate location using GPS and AGPS with given time in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10117363/how-to-get-the-most-accurate-location-using-gps-and-agps-with-given-time-in-andr)

Basically it depends on the phone's GPS and the current environment. Besides that, there's probably nothing you can do to further boost the location accuracy other than using GPS.